# MQ Max message length issue in browsing

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, xms

We have an .Net application connecting to MQ using XMS.NET. We are facing one issue as below.
-   We have one message of length around 5~5.5 MB in queue and if Max message length of channel is set to 4 MB then we are not able to browse message. But If I increase channel length to 6 MB then we are able to  read message.
-   But In other environment though Max message length of channel is too high then also message is not read and it is also not throwing any exception.
-   We are using MoveNext of IQueueBrowser of XMS.NET.

Please guide us……

Answer (score 0):

> But In other environment though Max message length of channel is too
>   high then also message is not read and it is also not throwing any
>   exception.

I don't know what you are putting in your Kool-Aid but that does not make any sense.  Any time you are dealing with messages larger than 4MB (default for MAXMSGL), most people, including me, recommend simply setting MAXMSGL to the max. i.e. 100MB.

Having a value much larger than the actual message size does NOT affect the processing of the message.  If you are getting issues then you need to debug your application.